# DropDownList not showing selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

i have edit view :

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownList("RoleID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleID, new {class="dropdownlistCustom" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleID)
</div>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        UserDetail userDetail=db.UserDetails.Find(id);
        if(userDetail!=null)
        {
           ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleStatus == "A"), "RoleID", "RoleName", userdetail.RoleID);
           return View(userdetail);
        }
    }
```

model:

```
[Display(Name = "Name Of the Role")]
public int RoleID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("RoleID")]
public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
```

eventhough i set `selectedValue` parameter from controller , `DropDownList` not showing selected value.

Comment: How do you post it to controller ? using BeginForm or javascript ?

Comment: i am trying on GET: /UserDetail/Edit/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can pass the value through `ViewBag`

```
ViewBag.ReportID = new SelectList(context, "ReportName","ReportName",userdetail.WorkLocation);
@Html.DropDownList("Report", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ReportID })
```

Answer (score 2):

Better try to set selected option in the datasource itself using SelectList

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.Add("Value1", "1");
list.Add("Value2", "2");
list.Add("Value3", "3");
var selectList = new SelectList(list,
          "Value", "Key", 
          "2"); // selected item's value "Value2" is selected.
ViewData["SelectedValue"] = selectList;

@Html.DropDownList("ddlValues", (SelectList)ViewData["SelectedValue"]) )
```

Comment: so what if i clicked the DropDownList it would show only the selected value ?  the thing is selected value should be at the top index so that when it comes to click the DropDownList  the first index value bind and show it on DropDownList